# IOS Splash and app icon not showing on simulator

Tags: ios8, ios-simulator

I am using ios 8.2 and i drag splash images and app icon by using asset catalog but they are not showing please on iPhone Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Your asset catalog in your main application isn't accessible from your application extension as they are two separate applications bundles that can only share Frameworks.

You will need to create a separate asset catalog in your action extensions folder and reference that one in your Targets.